# PowerApps - Office365Users.Manager failed:

Tags: powerapps

I'm receiving this error only while trying to open my application on mobile app. Other than that its working good on SharePoint and where i created it. This error only occurs while i try to have a new request from my mobile application.

**"Office365Users.Manager failed: The method 'Manager' has an invalid value for parameter 'userId'"  error only on Standalone Power App.**